# Is the usage of reinterpret_cast on a memcpy buffer UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given the code

```
struct A {};

auto obj = new A;
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
buffer.resize(sizeof(obj));
std::memcpy(buffer.data(), &obj, sizeof(obj));  // this copies the pointer, not the object!

// ...

auto ptr = *reinterpret_cast<A**>(buffer.data()); // is this UB?
delete ptr;
```

is the usage of `reinterpret_cast` in this case UB? I would say yes, because `memcpy` doesn't start the lifetime of an instance hence violating the strict aliasing rule (which is why `std::bit_cast` has been added to C++20).

And if I replace the cast with another `memcpy` (to read the pointer) would the program be well defined?

Comment: language lawyering aside, it's just plain wrong. It's the contents pointed at by `buffer.data()` that supposedly contains a pointer to `A`, not `buffer.data()` itself that is a pointer to `A`.

Comment: That should be `*reinterpret_cast<A**>(buffer.data());` to make any sense.

Comment: @flyx whoops fixed.

Comment: Neither the post nor comments make any sense. `delete ptr;` huh?

Comment: The "fix" makes even less sense. What are you trying to hold in the buffer? A copy of A or a copy of a pointer to A?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The idea is that `obj == ptr` if the code is well-defined.

Comment: Are there any alignment guarantees of the backing store allocated memory by a `std::vector`?  (I presume its guarantees are whatever its allocator guarantees.)

Comment: I think it breaks strict aliasing as well.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's perhaps *your* idea, bit the code is so hopelessly broken on so many levels that the original intent could be anything.

Comment: I'm sorry if this ins't the right venue but my curiosity took over my common sense, what is the deal with the Reinstate Monica nicks?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. There are some things wrong with this code (alignment and object creation, as far as I can see), but it’s pretty clear what the code intends to achieve. To say that the “original intent could be anything” in the context of this question is disingenuous and, frankly, unnecessarily hostile. There’s a clear, valid question attached here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No wait, I'm misreading something.

Comment: @anastaciu First hit on Google — https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5783/3512

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry about that, I don't use google, I use Ecosia and since there are so many nicks like that I couldn't quite find an answer to my question, I 've seen the logo though, many times, in users avatars. Thank you for that.

Comment: OK after re-reading the question, it is indeed UB because (1) the alignment requirements are potentially broken and (2) here is no `A*` object in the buffer. The standard says about the standard allocator::allocate function: "Returns: A pointer to the initial element of an array of storage of size `n * sizeof(T)`, aligned appropriately *for objects of type T*".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this code has undefined behavior. There is no object of type `A*` at the location pointed to by `buffer.data()`. All you did was copy the object representation of such a pointer into your vector [[basic.types]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#4). Since pointers are trivially copyable [[basic.types]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#9), if you were to copy back these bytes into an actual object of type `A*` and then `delete` the value of that, that would be well-defined [[basic.types]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#3). So this

```cpp
A* ptr;
std::memcpy(&ptr, buffer.data(), sizeof(ptr));
delete ptr;
```

would be fine.

Note that it is not the cast itself that invokes undefined behavior in your original example but your subsequent attempt to read the value of an object of type `A*` which does not exist where the pointer obtained via the cast points. All there exists where the pointer points is a sequence of objects of type `unsigned char`. The type `A*` is not a type that you may use to access the stored value of an object of type `unsigned char` [[basic.lval]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8)…

Comment: I believe this answer is correct yet the last sentence is a bit surprising, given that there is a good amount of existing code doing essentially what the question asks (virtually every custom container implementation, for a start), and there’s currently not really a good way around this in some cases.

Comment: `A* a_ptr; std::memcpy(&a_ptr, buffer.data(), sizeof(a_ptr));` to extract the pointer back out of the buffer.  Rather than the `reinterpret_cast` in Timo’s question.

Comment: Language lawyering aside, why is this actually UB? Strict Aliasing comes to mind, is there anything other to it?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel there is an object of type `unsigned char` there, perhaps more than one.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. ah, sure. Thanks for pointing that out. That indeed makes it a violation of the strict aliasing rule…

Comment: @KonradRudolph I removed the controversial sentence since it doesn't add anything to the answer itself. Nevertheless, I'm having trouble coming up with examples where doing something like this would be a defensible design choice. The only purpose for accessing the object representation of a pointer to begin with would be if you intent to serialize that pointer. Serializing pointers is rarely useful. The only application I could imagine is on-the-fly compression and decompression of the in-memory representation of some data structure or something like that…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Of course it’s not defensible, since it’s UB. But initiating object lifetime is really hard in (current) C++, and tons of (otherwise high-quality!) code fails to do it properly, see [p0593r2 §2.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html#dynamic-construction-of-arrays) in particular, but also §2.2. And since you mention compression: that’s actually what my company does, and let’s just say that our code base does not pay attention to these issue in the least (admittedly, since much of it is derived from idiomatic C).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I removed the sentence in question. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph looks like [p0593r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r5.html) is the latest draft and according to §4 it might be added to C++20 as a DR.